# Scala 2.13.1 - Error: Error Symbol 'type org.scalatest.WordSpec' is missing from the classpath

Tags: scala, playframework, scalatest

I have a very simple sbt project.

**[build.sbt]**

```
name := "some"

version := "0.1"

scalaVersion := "2.13.1"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.scalatest"           %% "scalatest-mustmatchers"  % "3.2.0-M1" % Test,
  "org.scalatestplus.play"  %% "scalatestplus-play"    % "5.0.0" % "test",
  "org.scalatestplus"       %% "scalatestplus-mockito" % "1.0.0-M2" % Test
)
```

**[build.properties]**

```
sbt.version = 1.3.7
```

**[src/test/scala/PersonSpec.scala]**

```
import org.scalatestplus.play.PlaySpec

class PersonSpec extends PlaySpec {
}
```

When I run `test` in sbt I got this error:

```
[info] Compiling 1 Scala source to /Users/.../target/scala-2.13/test-classes ...
[error] /Users/.../src/test/scala/PersonSpec.scala:4:26: Symbol 'type org.scalatest.WordSpec' is missing from the classpath.
[error] This symbol is required by 'class org.scalatestplus.play.PlaySpec'.
[error] Make sure that type WordSpec is in your classpath and check for conflicting dependencies with `-Ylog-classpath`.
[error] A full rebuild may help if 'PlaySpec.class' was compiled against an incompatible version of org.scalatest.
[error] class PersonSpec extends PlaySpec {
[error]                          ^
[error] one error found
[error] (Test / compileIncremental) Compilation failed
[error] Total time: 5 s, completed Feb 4, 2020 11:50:27 AM
```

How can I fix this error?

Comment: seems like a binary compatibility issue. I think `scalatestplus-play` was compiled against a previous version of `scalatestplus-mockito` and the this `1.0.0-M2` version does not maintain binary compatibility with that one.

Comment: Thank you Sarvesh, I'm going to check that.